# Windows 10 network share (by gpo in domain) not showing in explorer

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, mappeddrive

I map 2 drives from the same samba server via the same GPO in a domain. I have (at least) one Windows 10 (1803) client PC, that only maps one drive (K). The other drive (L):

- is **not** shown in explorer
- is shown in cmd with `net use`
- is shown in the dialog used to connect network shares via explorer
- can be accessed via UNC path
- can be used to access subfolders via explorer (e.g. "L:\my folder\")
- can be accessed via `cmd` (e.g. `C:\l:` --> `L:\`)

[image]

According to smbstatus, protocol version 3.0 is used

```
~# smbstatus | grep 192.168.5.142
5262      3000051       users         192.168.5.142 (ipv4:192.168.5.142:49757) SMB3_00     
K      5262   192.168.5.142  Wed May 29 13:11:13 2019
L      5262   192.168.5.142  Wed May 29 13:11:14 2019
```

What did not work:

- SMB Version 1.0 Client is enabled on the client
- Hacking the registry (deleting  \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2##*) did not solve the problem
- mapping as "replace" or "update" did not make a difference

What did work:

- when mapping as "replace" in GPO, manually running `gpupdate` after login brings the drive back - this is not an option but might give you some clues.

I cannot see any errors in `eventvwr` (applications, system or group policy)

Any clues?

Comment: This question is not abandoned, but the error did not show up again for now. I will report back if it comes up again.

Comment: I do experience the exact same issue, same behavior (`gpudpate` shows the drives, but normally none are shown, and they are usable in `cmd`). This is on a Windows 10 1809 machine. So far the problem still persists, do you have an idea maybe what might have changed the behaviour in your case?

Answer (score 1):

The Group Policy (in User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps) has an option to add hidden drives. They work the same and show up in `net use`, but are hidden from the GUI.

[image: New Drive Properties]

Could you have missed this?

Comment: these are set to "no change". And this is working on other machines (Win7 and 10). I'll try to force showing it and report back.